# Indefinite pronoun in negative sentence

Tags: pronouns, negation

Can we write "Everybody didn't know he was a famous inventor."

Comment: No, it's more idiomatic the other way round: 'nobody knew...'

Comment: If you want to use "everybody", choose a wording that doesn't include "not". For instance, "Everybody was unaware ..."

Comment: Sure, if we meant "Not everyone knew ...." Any questions?

Comment: @marcellothearcane Why not?

Comment: @Kris no idea. It just doesn't sound right

Comment: @marcellothearcane It's because you may not have considered the other interpretation.

Comment: But hey this is **not** a proof reading Q.

Comment: @Kris If we mean 'Not everyone knew' (but some did), surely it's much more idiomatic to say it that way?

Comment: @KateBunting I only meant to say that it's not necessarily incorrect. "Yes we can," in answer to the OP's question.

Comment: Yes, you can write the sentence as you did. (It's grammatical.) But its meaning is ambiguous. (As the current answer shows.) Did you have a more specific question about the sentence than just "Can we?"

Answer (score 1):

As we see in the comments,

> Everybody didn't know X

is ambiguous.  It could mean

> Not everybody knew X = at least one person was ignorant of X

or it could mean

> Nobody knew X = everyone was ignorant of X